# jQuery Cookie Toggle Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So because my function uses `toggle()` to hide and show a panel, Its really hard to actually tell when I should set a cookie and how I would integrate it.

Code:

```
/ Collapse ibox function
$('.collapse-link:not(.binded)').addClass("binded").click( function() {
    var ibox = $(this).closest('div.ibox');
    var button = $(this).find('i');
    var content = ibox.find('div.ibox-content');

    if($.cookie("chat") !== 'show'){
        content.slideUp(200);
        $.cookie("chat", "hide");
    }

    button.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
    ibox.toggleClass('').toggleClass('border-bottom');
    setTimeout(function () {
        ibox.resize();
        ibox.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
    }, 50);

});
```

I have no idea how to implement the `$.cookie("chat")` section.

Comment: Please describe the main idea of your code and why you want to implement `$.cookie("chat")`.

Comment: Just to slide down and up (Show and Hide) the chat.

Comment: Okay try to provide a fiddle or at least add your HTML code.

Comment: Its really not needed I have it showing and hiding I just cant get it to remember if its hidden or shown via cookies.

Comment: Where is the part of code that _showing and hiding_?

Comment: var content is whats being hid.